# Is There Documentation for xUnit++

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++

xUnit++ isn't the same thing as xUnit, and google doesn't point me to any good documentation. The xUnit++ site has a Wiki, with about five pages of general stuff, but no real specifics and no tutorials.

Does anyone know of any relatively complete, or detailed, documentation of xUnit++. Also, if you know of any tutorials, that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't. I opened an issue about this on the author's homepage over a month ago. The link is here.

https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit/issue/13/tutorial-and-quick-start

It can be assumed that he's busy because good programmers are usually swamped.

I would suggest making a bitbucket account to comment on the issue, or asking the author to move his repository to something like GitHub, where the community would take care of the rest of the work for him.

It might be a little bit difficult because he is currently using mecurial for his version control.

Not much of an answer, but there are other people looking for the same information as you.

[Change 2016-05-10]
I started using The [Catch Framework](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) for doing unit test in C and C++ approximately 2 months after answering this question. It is fairly well documented and in active development on GitHub. It might be worth a try.

Comment: @EoRaptor013 I just got a reponse from the author and he said that he's working on more comprehensive documentation as we speak. (This is of course as of the date of this comment) If you are able to make any headway in using the frame work, please document it and post it on a personal blog or other media so that others can use it. I will be doing the same.

Comment: Three years later and there still isn't any documentation. It was only by chance I even learned that it had extensibility points.